# ngif component shows shortly then disappear

Tags: angular

I have following in html:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav" >
            <li><a *ngIf="isLoggedIn" routerLink="/welcome/in28minutes" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li><a *ngIf="isLoggedIn" routerLink="/todos" class="nav-link">Todos</a></li>
        </ul>
```

The problem is that those 2 `<li>` shows briefly then disappear when the page is loaded, although the user isn't logged in.

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn = false;

  constructor(public hardcodedAuthenticationService : HardcodedAuthenticationService) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.isUserLoggedIn()
  }

  async isUserLoggedIn() {
    this.isLoggedIn = await this.hardcodedAuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn() // this return false
  }
}
```

isLoggedIn is initially set to false. On init, I call `this.hardcodedAuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()` but this always return false, so isLoggedIn is always false. So in html, those 2 `<LI>` shouldn't show. But it briefly show then disappear. I don't know why.

---

```
async isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user: any;

    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      user = sessionStorage.getItem('authenticaterUser')
    }
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      user = this._cookieService.get('authenticaterUser');
    }
    return !(user === null)
  }
```

Comment: Is `hardcodedAuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn` async? Can you share the code for that method?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky no I don't think it is async. added this function on the post.

Comment: If ngIf put at ul level, does it work?

Comment: In `isUserLoggedIn`, try `return !!user`. Your current code returns `true` when `user` is `undefined`, which is the default value.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I think it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was return !(user === null), returning true.